# Keep a value selected as default in dropdownmenu flutter

Tags: flutter

I have dropdown menu with main category also subcategory.in my Worker registration i am calling this dropdown with API,so if i open worker registration page i need to select Worker as default also change the subcategory dropdown based on the default value in this case worker,in main category there is only 4 items returns

**1:Worker
2:Shop
3.rental equipment
4.contractor**

These are the 4 main category items.so when i open worker registration page i need worker as default in dropdown.the problem is if i initialize the value as default the subcategory drop down doesn't work

[image: This is what i want]

```
 Flexible(
              flex: 0,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, top: 15),
                child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 45,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueGrey)),
                  child: DropdownButton(
                    isExpanded: true,
                    itemHeight: 50,
                    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                    iconSize: 40,
                    underline: SizedBox(),
                    hint: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "Category",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.black54),
                      ),
                    ),
                    value: _selectedmenu,
                    onChanged: (NewValues) {
                      _selectedmenu = NewValues;

                      setState(() {});
                    },
                    items: home_model.map((menu) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: language != "ml"
                              ? Text(menu.english)
                              : Text(menu.malayalam),
                        ),
                        value: menu.id,
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: I think you have everything correct if _selectedmenu is initialized to Worker. You should remove the hint, maybe Hint is shown instead of default value. But you will get an error because  _selectedmenu = NewValues; is not inside setState(). Wrap it inside setState.
And I am also a malayalee:)

Comment: ivadem malayalees again@Bensal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `onChanged` of the `DropDownButton` to:

```
onChanged: (value) {
   setState(() {
     _selectedmenu = value;
   });
},
```

And initialize `_selectedmenu` with the id of the `Worker` item, e.g.

```
var _selectedmenu = 'worker';
```

Comment: but the problem is i have this subcategory based on the main category.i am passing the value to next the api,so i will get the filtered data in subcategory menu.after i changed to default value to selectedmenu,the subcategory fields doesn't work @Mobina

Comment: Can you show a picture of what you mean? I don't get it. @MorbiusBlack

Comment: i have updated the question with image and some detailed paragraph @Mobina

Comment: Have you tried initializing the sub menu too? @MorbiusBlack

Comment: i figured it out ,i have posted what i have done,thank for the help,.but it is not good way i think i am not sure.if they change the id or update or something,this will throw bug right.just asking is there any way with out hard coding the id to the initialized value.@Mobina

Comment: What if you initiale `_selectedMenu` with the id of the first element' of `home_model`? @MorbiusBlack

Comment: if they add more main category in future,it won't work i think,the order of main category can change if you add more or udpate may be...@Mobina

Comment: You can add a condition on the `item.english` to check if it was "Workers"  then set it as initial value(I assume this field contains the category name of the item). @MorbiusBlack

Comment: hmm..i will try that@Mobina

Answer (score 0):

**Initialized the  _selectedmenu with default worker id and removed the onchanged and DropdownMenuItem and added to Text with worker with condition because i have this localization integrated into it.By passing  initialized _selectedmenu to the subcategory api and called the api in setState in the main class**

```
String _selectedmenu = "5ef1b61930def32b3cbe7890";
    
            Flexible(
                  flex: 0,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, top: 15),
                    child: Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      height: 45,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueGrey)),
                      child: DropdownButton(
                        isExpanded: true,
                        itemHeight: 50,
                        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                        iconSize: 40,
                        underline: SizedBox(),
                        hint: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: language != "ml"
                              ? Text(
                                  "Worker",
                                  style:
                                      TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.black),
                                )
                              : Text(
                                  "ജോലിക്കാർ",
                                  style:
                                      TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.black),
                                ),
                        ),
                        value: _selectedmenu,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```